# ActionCable unsubscribe callback not working when iOS client send "unsubscribe"

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

Remote iOS client successfully connects to me, send subscribe command (it works fine), but on "unsubscribe" command I get next error:

```
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"Assessor::StationChannel", "station_id": 1}
Could not execute command from {"command"=>"unsubscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"Assessor::StationChannel\", \"station_id\": 1}"}) [NoMethodError - undefined method `unsubscribe_from_channel' for nil:NilClass]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:44:in `remove_subscription' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:40:in `remove' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:16:in `execute_command' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:88:in `dispatch_websocket_message' | /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:58:in `block in invoke'
```

Subscribe message format:

```
{"command": "subscribe", "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"Assessor::StationChannel\", \"station_id\": 1}"}
```

Unsubscribe message format:

```
{"command": "unsubscribe", "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"Assessor::StationChannel\", \"station_id\": 1}"}
```

I cannot reproduce this problem on localhost, so maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: Can you format your error message and commands to eliminate scrolling.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the proper way to cleanup and disconnect a connection? In context of a mobile client/ios

Answer (score 4):

I saw a similar error. I was trying to unsubscribe via the client (JS). I eventually figured out it was because the javascript to .remove(subscription) takes the subscription and not the subscription identifier.

This is how I got it to work without error. Perhaps it will help you find out why you are getting the error from the server side.

```
subscription = App.cable.subscriptions.subscriptions[0]
App.cable.subscriptions.remove(subscription);
```

(Note, I'm just pulling the first subscription from the array, TODO: Search for the subscription I want to remove)

Here is the bug I was seeing and how I eventually found the source code/answer. I ran these from the webclient console:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: 2})
```

That line works and I get a "... is transmitting the subscription confirmation" on stdout for rails s

```
App.cable.subscriptions.remove({channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: 2})
```

That line blows up, yells at my kids, and insults my wife which looks like:

```
[NoMethodError - undefined method `unsubscribe_from_channel' for nil:NilClass]: /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.0.1/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:44:in `remove_subscription'
```

I also noted the following line before the crash.

```
Unsubscribing from channel:
```

The code to produce that is: logger.info "Unsubscribing from channel: #{data['identifier']}". Which means it wasn't finding the data['identifier']. So I started debugging and I see that line 88 of base.rb in actioncable only gets {"command":"unsubscribe"} and not something like {"command":"unsubscribe", "identifier":" (channel name here)}

Which brought me to action_cable.js. (I would have started here, but I hate JS.). Here was my problem: function(**subscription**). I was sending the identifier and not the subscription object.

```
Subscriptions.prototype.remove = function(subscription) {
  this.forget(subscription);
  if (!this.findAll(subscription.identifier).length) {
    this.sendCommand(subscription, "unsubscribe");
  }
  return subscription;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: 2})` returns a subscription object you have to pass that into the `remove` function

`var subscription = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: 2});`

Then later

`App.cable.subscriptions.remove(subscription);`

Comment: Works for me (in 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

After several tries I eventually figured it out. Late reply but this worked for me hope it does for you.

```
App["identifier"].disconnected() #e.g  App["chat_4"].disconnect()
=> YourChannel stopped streaming from chat_4 #rails terminal
```

Above is the line to stop the streaming and below is how you subscribe to the channel

```
App['chat' + id] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 
     'YourChannel', chat_id: id}, {

     disconnected: function () {
       App.cable.subscriptions.remove(this)
     },
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I suffered from the same issue. None of the answers above worked for me and in fact, at least in Rails 5.0.1, they are incorrect. It is a frontend issue all right, but here's why it doesn't matter whether you call `App.yourChannelName.unsubscribe()` or `App.yourChannelName.remove(App.yourChannelName)`

Eg. if you have something like this (example code is in coffeescript, so ignore the lack of vars and other stuff from vanilla JS):

```
App.yourChannel = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'YourChannel', id: id})
...
// do stuff, execute callbacks, whatnot
...
// try to execute unsubscribe
App.yourChannel.unsubscribe()
```

The `.unsubscribe()` is a method on Subscription prototype which only does `return this.consumer.subscriptions.remove(this)`

The `this.consumer.subscriptions` returns the instance of your subscription, in example above, it would be `App.yourChannel` and calls `.remove` method with the instance of Subscription - ie. with `App.yourChannel`

So `App.yourChannel.unsubscribe()` is the same as calling `App.cable.subscriptions.remove(App.yourChannel)` (or whichever variable you choose to store the instance of Subscription in.

I have also been seeing the same error as OP, except that in my case, it was caused by `App.yourChannel.unsubscribe()` being called two times - the first time it was called immediately after I received specific data via the channel and the second time was due to a custom cleanup being run in a specific scenario before the `App.yourChannel` was re-subscribed.

So if you see a similar error, I suggest you look at the server logs.
You'll probably see something like

```
Registered connection (some-id) <-- initial subscription
YourChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
...
// other stuff while user is subscribed to the channel
...
Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"YourChannel","id":"some-id"} <-- initial unsubscribe call
YourChannel stopped streaming from your_channel_some-id
// some other requests potentially, perhaps some DB queries
...
// there are no requests to subscribe to the channel with the some-id, eg. you won't see this
// Registered connection (some-id)
// YourChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation

Unsubscribing from channel: {"channel":"YourChannel","id":"some-id"} <-- duplicated unsubscribe call
Could not execute command from {"command"=>"unsubscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"YourChannel\",\"id\":\"some-id\"}"}) [NoMethodError - undefined method `unsubscribe_from_channel' for nil:NilClass]:
```

Basically, the user subscribes, unsubscribes, then tries to unsubscribe again (even though they are not subscribed to that channel anymore)